Terraform or Azure tries using wrong storage account type
I'm creating a new storage account, storage container, storage blob, service plan, and finally - function. Everything but the last one is created successfully, and the last step fails with a message:
 creating Linux App Service (Subscription: "6bbf2436-dd82-400e-8476-a022f1f9eacc"
│ Resource Group Name: "mtr-resources"
│ Site Name: "mtr-hello-function11"): performing CreateOrUpdate: unexpected status 400 (400 Bad Request) with response: {"Code":"BadRequest","Message":"There was a conflict. The remote name could not be resolved:      
│ 'mtrstorageyqo20pyfgz.file.core.windows.net'","Target":null,"Details":[{"Message":"There was a conflict. The remote name could not be resolved:
│ 'mtrstorageyqo20pyfgz.file.core.windows.net'"},{"Code":"BadRequest"},{"ErrorEntity":{"ExtendedCode":"01020","MessageTemplate":"There was a conflict. {0}","Parameters":["The remote name could not be resolved:
│ 'mtrstorageyqo20pyfgz.file.core.windows.net'"],"Code":"BadRequest","Message":"There was a conflict. The remote name could not be resolved: 'mtrstorageyqo20pyfgz.file.core.windows.net'"}}],"Innererror":null}

If you look closely, you'll see this string: mtrstorageyqo20pyfgz.file.core.windows.net - which is obviously wrong, because it should contain the word "blob", not "file". Even more so, because I can inspect the created storage account in Azure, and see its type is Account Kind is BlobStorage. Here are the relevant terraform definitions:
resource "random_string" "random_storage_account_suffix" {
  length  = 10
  special = false
  upper   = false
  numeric = true
  lower   = true
}


resource "azurerm_storage_account" "mtr_storage" {
  name                     = "mtrstorage${random_string.random_storage_account_suffix.result}"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.mtr_rg.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.mtr_rg.location
  account_kind             = "BlobStorage"
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"

  tags = {
    environment = "${var.environment_name}"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_storage_container" "mtr_hello_function_container" {
  name                  = "hello-function-releases"
  storage_account_name  = var.storage_account_name
  container_access_type = "private"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_blob" "mtr_hello_function_blob" {
  name                   = "MTR.ListBlobsFunction.publish.zip"
  storage_account_name   = var.storage_account_name
  storage_container_name = azurerm_storage_container.mtr_hello_function_container.name
  type                   = "Block"
  source                 = "./example_code/MTR.ListBlobsFunction/MTR.ListBlobsFunction.publish.zip"

  depends_on = [ null_resource.run_pre_hello_powershell_script ]
}

resource "azurerm_service_plan" "mtr_hello_function_svc_plan" {
  name                = "mtr-hello-function-svc-plan"
  location            = var.resource_group_location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  os_type             = "Linux"
  sku_name            = "Y1"
  # sku_name            = "B1" # this doesn't work with zip package download for some reason - consumption tier needs to be used

  tags = {
    environment = "${var.environment_name}"
  }
}

data "azurerm_storage_account_blob_container_sas" "storage_account_blob_container_sas_for_hello" {
  connection_string = var.storage_account_primary_connection_string
  container_name    = azurerm_storage_container.mtr_hello_function_container.name

  start  = timeadd(timestamp(), "-10m")
  expiry = timeadd(timestamp(), "10m")

  permissions {
    read   = true
    add    = false
    create = false
    write  = false
    delete = false
    list   = true
  }
}

resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "mtr_hello_function" {
  name                       = "mtr-hello-function11"
  location                   = var.resource_group_location
  resource_group_name        = var.resource_group_name
  service_plan_id            = azurerm_service_plan.mtr_hello_function_svc_plan.id
  storage_account_name       = var.storage_account_name
  storage_account_access_key = var.storage_account_primary_access_key

  app_settings = {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME"    = "dotnet"
    "WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE"    = "https://${var.storage_account_name}.blob.core.windows.net/${azurerm_storage_container.mtr_hello_function_container.name}/${azurerm_storage_blob.mtr_hello_function_blob.name}${data.azurerm_storage_account_blob_container_sas.storage_account_blob_container_sas_for_hello.sas}"
    "AzureWebJobsStorage"         = var.storage_account_primary_connection_string
    "AzureWebJobsDisableHomepage" = "true"
  }

  site_config {
    application_stack {
      dotnet_version              = "8.0"
      use_dotnet_isolated_runtime = true
    }

    cors {
      allowed_origins = ["*"]
    }
  }

  tags = {
    environment = "${var.environment_name}"
  }
}

At this point I'm not even sure if that's a Terraform issue, or Azure issue, but I know that storage account address is wrong, because if I substitute the file word with blob, use the correct container and blob names + SAS key, I can download the file.

Why are you creating a SAS for the Function App to use when authenticating the storage account? Without explicit reason to do otherwise your default here should be to assign a system-assigned managed identity to the Function App and have it use that to authenticate with the Function App, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity

I don't think that's the reason for the error I'm seeing. It doesn't even get to the part where it would download the blob. Or am I wrong?

Where is the null_resource.run_pre_hello_powershell_script definition? And why do you need it?

@RuiJarimba it's running the dotnet publish command, then it packages the output into a zip file that I'm later uploading. Isn't it how it should be done?

I'd honestly avoid running custom scripts inside Terraform - it will make your IaC code harder to maintain and is not guaranteed to be platform-independent. I'd run the dotnet publish command BEFORE running any terraform xxx commands.

You're creating a storage account with a random name but you're using var.storage_account_name in the other resources.

The problem is with the account kind here:
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "mtr_storage" {
  name                     = "mtrstorage${random_string.random_storage_account_suffix.result}"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.mtr_rg.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.mtr_rg.location
  account_kind             = "BlobStorage"
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"

  tags = {
    environment = "${var.environment_name}"
  }
}

Please note that BlobStorage account kind does not support File service. If you need to use File service, please choose another account kind (Standard general-purpose v2 or Standard general-purpose v1).
UPDATE
Based on the information provided here, when Function App is running under Consumption or Premium plan, the code and configuration is stored in Azure File Storage. Since the storage account kind is BlobStorage which does not support File Service, deployment of Function App is failing.

I'm not using file service, at least not consciously. Where do you see me using it?

Please check the error message as it is complaining about file service endpoint. Even though you may not be using it directly in your code, the underlying infrastructure might be using it.

But how do I confirm it? I'm not doing anything manually, configuration of the storage account in the portal says it's a blob store, the endpoints I can see that it's exposing are also for blob, not file.

Please see this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/storage-considerations?tabs=azure-cli#important-considerations (1st bullet point). Considering your App Service Plan is Consumption plan, Azure Function will use File Storage Service to store the code and configuration settings.

Also, look at the Storage Accounts Requirement on the same link as well (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/storage-considerations?tabs=azure-cli#storage-account-requirements).

Great! I am glad to hear that your issue is resolved. I have updated my answer to include the information provided in the comments.

I think there are a few issues with your code:

You're creating a storage account with a random name but you're using var.storage_account_name in the other resources instead of azurerm_storage_account.mtr_storage.name
You should set the access key, connection strings and others using the properties from the managed storage account (e.g. azurerm_storage_account.mtr_storage.primary_connection_string) instead of using variables
Consider using random_id instead of random_string, which is more suitable for unique IDs (as recommended in the random_string docs)
I'd honestly avoid running custom scripts inside Terraform (provisioners should be a last resort). As a workaround, run the dotnet publish command BEFORE running any terraform xxx commands
Consider using shorter names for the resources (hello or hello_sas as opposed to storage_account_blob_container_sas_for_hello)

Finally, the code with some of the fixes I mentioned. Please note that this sample was not tested, but I hope it helps to solve at least some of your issues.
resource "random_string" "random_storage_account_suffix" {
  length  = 10
  special = false
  upper   = false
  numeric = true
  lower   = true
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "mtr_storage" {
  name                     = "mtrstorage${random_string.random_storage_account_suffix.result}"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.mtr_rg.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.mtr_rg.location
  account_kind             = "BlobStorage"
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"

  tags = {
    environment = "${var.environment_name}"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_storage_container" "mtr_hello_function_container" {
  name                  = "hello-function-releases"
  storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.mtr_storage.name
  container_access_type = "private"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_blob" "mtr_hello_function_blob" {
  name                   = "MTR.ListBlobsFunction.publish.zip"
  storage_account_name   = azurerm_storage_account.mtr_storage.name
  storage_container_name = azurerm_storage_container.mtr_hello_function_container.name
  type                   = "Block"
  source                 = "./example_code/MTR.ListBlobsFunction/MTR.ListBlobsFunction.publish.zip"

  # Consider generating the file BEFORE running any terraform commands
  depends_on = [null_resource.run_pre_hello_powershell_script]
}

resource "azurerm_service_plan" "mtr_hello_function_svc_plan" {
  name                = "mtr-hello-function-svc-plan"
  location            = var.resource_group_location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  os_type             = "Linux"
  sku_name            = "Y1"
  # sku_name            = "B1" # this doesn't work with zip package download for some reason - consumption tier needs to be used

  tags = {
    environment = "${var.environment_name}"
  }
}

data "azurerm_storage_account_blob_container_sas" "storage_account_blob_container_sas_for_hello" {
  connection_string = azurerm_storage_account.mtr_storage.primary_connection_string
  container_name    = azurerm_storage_container.mtr_hello_function_container.name

  start  = timeadd(timestamp(), "-10m")
  expiry = timeadd(timestamp(), "10m")

  permissions {
    read   = true
    add    = false
    create = false
    write  = false
    delete = false
    list   = true
  }
}

resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "mtr_hello_function" {
  name                       = "mtr-hello-function11"
  location                   = var.resource_group_location
  resource_group_name        = var.resource_group_name
  service_plan_id            = azurerm_service_plan.mtr_hello_function_svc_plan.id
  storage_account_name       = var.storage_account_name
  storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.mtr_storage.primary_access_key

  app_settings = {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME"    = "dotnet"
    "WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE"    = "https://${var.storage_account_name}.blob.core.windows.net/${azurerm_storage_container.mtr_hello_function_container.name}/${azurerm_storage_blob.mtr_hello_function_blob.name}${data.azurerm_storage_account_blob_container_sas.storage_account_blob_container_sas_for_hello.sas}"
    "AzureWebJobsStorage"         = azurerm_storage_account.mtr_storage.primary_connection_string
    "AzureWebJobsDisableHomepage" = "true"
  }

  site_config {
    application_stack {
      dotnet_version              = "8.0"
      use_dotnet_isolated_runtime = true
    }

    cors {
      allowed_origins = ["*"]
    }
  }

  tags = {
    environment = "${var.environment_name}"
  }
}


I simplified my infra. I have two modules - one with „shared” components that output those keys/names etc. and the other one that consumes them via the use of variables. Nothing is missing here, everything is connected with the right data. Funny thing though - the problem went away when I switched from Y1 to B1. Now I have different problems though…
